# Fahrenheit/Celsius Converter (GUI)

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        float num1, num2, result;
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
        result = num1 - 32*5/9;
        jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Need to know what I'm doing wrong here. Trying to crate a gui that goes from fahrenheit to celsius but when ever I enter a number and click the "calculate" button it gives me errors.

Comment: Post the errors it gives.

Comment: You're doing int division. You likely want to do `(num1 - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0`